# How I can get id form when I press the submit button?

Tags: javascript, html

When I press the submit button I need to find out the form id and pass input values with post method via ajax. Can I put the `form` inside the `tr` tag? How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
alert("hello");
 var formid = $(this).closest("form[id]").attr('id');;

alert(formid) });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
     <form id='idForm'>
          <td><input type='input' value='12345' name='data1'></td>
          <td><input type='input' value='12345' name='data2'></td>
          <td><button type='submit' form='idForm'>Send</button></td>
     </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But when I try to check result inside `Alert()` it displays undefined.

Comment: You should add your html code as well. :)

Comment: Where in your page did you put your jQuery (in the head? end of body?)?

Comment: Try with ```var formid = $(this).parent("form").attr("id");```

Comment: Hi, I  update my post, thanks for your help.

Comment: Use [a validator](http://validator.nu). Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a form there. The browser is trying to recover from your error and the result is not what you expect. https://i.imgur.com/Cq38lhI.png

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to give `id` or `class` attribute to the tags you want to manipulate.
Its better to write your html like this and you can get the tag value you want with jQuery

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
  var input1 = $('#input1').val();
  var input2 = $('#input2').val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
     <form id='idForm'>
          <td><input id="input1" type='input' value='12345' name='data1'></td>
          <td><input id="input2" type='input' value='12345' name='data2'></td>
          <td><button type='submit' form='idForm'>Send</button></td>
     </form>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` element will have an attribute pointing to the form it's contained within, so you should be able to simply change how you get the form ID to fix the issue.

Try changing this line...

```
var formid = $(this).closest("form[id]").attr('id');
```

To something like this...

```
var formid = this.form.id;
```

Or a more jQuery way of doing it...

```
var formid = $(this.form).attr('id');
```

And, yes, you can put the `<form>` element in the `<tr>` element, however, you need to have a `<td>` in the `<tr>` as well, not have the `<td>` in the form.

Proper form would look more like this...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form id="idForm">
                <input id="input1" type="input" value="12345" name="data1">
                <input id="input2" type="input" value="12345" name="data2">
                <button type="submit" form="idForm">Send</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or this, which is probably closer to what you are going for...

```
<form id="idForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="input1" type="input" value="12345" name="data1"></td>
            <td><input id="input2" type="input" value="12345" name="data2"></td>
            <td><button type="submit" form="idForm">Send</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```